# Erro ao gerar código de barras usando JasperSoft

Tags: java, jsf, jasper-reports, jaspersoft-studio

Tentando gerar códigos de barras de produtos, usando `Barcode4j 2.1` do `JasperSoft 6.5.1`, mas ao rodar na página JSF da esse erro:

```
   javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/batik/bridge/UserAgent
```

E exibe o PDF em branco.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sendo que, no programa JasperSoft exibe normalmente o PDF com o código.

`CodigoBarras.jrxml`

```
        <componentElement>
            <reportElement x="15" y="23" width="100" height="30" uuid="9127b2ca-8116-450e-a692-7c17bdd12b43"/>
            <jr:Codabar xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                <jr:codeExpression><![CDATA[$F{codigobarra}]]></jr:codeExpression>
            </jr:Codabar>
        </componentElement>
```

A `classe.java` que executa o .jasper esta normal, utilizo em outras impressões e geração de PDF.

Answer (score 1):

Verifique se no seu `pom.xml` tem a dependência `batik-bridge`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>batik</groupId>
    <artifactId>batik-bridge</artifactId>
    <version>1.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Também verifique se você está usando fonts.jar

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasperreports-fonts</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Allan Braga, ja tem essas duas dependências no pom, achava que com elas ja resolvia o problema

Comment: Nao resolveu o problema ?  Porque esse problema é referente a falta de biblioteca...

Comment: Resolvi usando `barbecue` em vez do `barcode4J`. Obrigrado